# The polynomial where only the terms in the multinomial series where each variable's exponent is $>0$ are kept?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, terminology, special-functions

I'm wondering if there's a special polynomial with a name out there with $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$ as variables that's defined like this:

$$
\sum_{\substack{i_1>0,i_2>0, \ldots,i_k>0 \\ i_1 +i_2+\cdots+i_k=n}} \frac{n!}{i_1! i_2! \cdots i_k!} x_1^{i_1} x_2^{i_2}\cdots x_k^{i_k}
$$

Comment: This is the multinomial formula, or multinomial theorem, a generalization of Newton's binomial formula. It is the expansion of $(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k)^n$.

Comment: @ManolitoPérez I think you guys didn't notice that $i_1>0,i_2>0,...,i_k>0$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think you guys didn't notice that $i_1>0,i_2>0,...,i_k>0 $

Comment: My apologies: indeed I did not, despite the title.

Comment: This form might help: $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\int_0^{x_1}\cdots\int_0^{x_k} (u_1+\cdots+u_k)^{n-k}du_1\cdots du_k,$$ which appears to also be: $$\sum_{J\subseteq[k]}(-1)^{k-\#J}\left(\sum_{j\in J} x_j\right)^n.$$

Comment: @anon Has such a function being studied before? I'm looking for some asymptotic results on this function.

Comment: @tmy1018: I wouldn't be surprised if some version is somewhere in *Enumerative Combinatorics*, but I've never seen a name or any special attention attached to it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that either.